# Como registrar uma Dll pelo Delphi no Windows XP?

Tags: delphi, dll, delphi-xe2

Preciso registrar uma dll pelo Delphi (xe2) no Windows XP, porém ao executar o método o windows abre uma janela "Executar como" onde precisa indicar o usuário que irá executar a ação. Mesmo meu usuario sendo administrador na máquina.

Utilizei o seguinte método para registro da Dll:

```
procedure TForm1.ExecAdmin(Programa, Parametros: string);
var sei: TShellExecuteInfo;
begin

  ZeroMemory(@sei, SizeOf(sei));

  sei.cbSize := SizeOf(TShellExecuteInfo);
  sei.Wnd := Application.Handle;
  sei.fMask := SEE_MASK_FLAG_DDEWAIT or SEE_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI;
  sei.lpVerb := PChar('runas');
  sei.lpFile := PChar(Programa);

  if Parametros <> '' then
    sei.lpParameters := PChar(Parametros);

  sei.nShow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;

  ShellExecuteEx(@sei);

end;
```

A chamada do método:

```
ExecAdmin('regsvr32.exe', '/s c:/sistema/msxml5.dll');
```

Duvidas:

a) Precisa de privilégio de Administrador para registrar a dll?
b) Como executar o método de forma silenciosa, sem que apareça a caixa de seleção de usuário?

Comment: Este programa que você está fazendo irá distribuir ou vender. O ideal é utilizar um programa que cria um instalador para a sua aplicação (inno setup por exemplo), ou colocar o programa na raiz do sistema, onde ele será executado.
Tive muitos problemas com DLL, resolvi colocando na pasta onde fica o .exe do sistema é instalado, e incluído no arquivo que gera o instalador. Quanto ao regsvr32.exe, precisa de privilégio de administrador e o '/s' é o  silencioso.